# How to colspan tr table from the start of the table

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

i want to start the colspan from the second column i mean from the name:
[image]

[image]

```
<table width="100%">
  <thead style="background-color: lightgray;">
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 30px;"></td>
       <td><p>Name</p></td>
    <td><p>ID</p></td>
    <td><p>GPS date</p></td>
    <td><p>Adresse</p></td>
    <td><p>Company</p></td>
    </tr>  
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="device in MyDeviceObject">
      <td>
        <button ng-if="device.expanded" ng-click="device.expanded = false">-</button>
        <button ng-if="!device.expanded" ng-click="device.expanded = true">+</button>
      </td>
      <td><p>{{device.name}}</p></td>
      <td><p>{{device.uniqueid}}</p></td>
      <td><p>{{device.devicetime}}</p></td>
      <td><p>{{device.adress}}</p></td>
      <td><p>{{device.company}}</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr  ng-if="device.expanded" ng-repeat-end="">
      <td  colspan="6">gfhgfjhfjtjrtkjy</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

please can anyone tell me how i can colspan from the name??

Comment: This is not very clear...so you want to create a new row after all rows have been rendered and to add on second column a colspan of 6?

Comment: i want the colspan starts from the name the second column

Comment: Add a `td` before it.

Comment: As @Abhitalks said, add a td before your td..

Comment: thanks abhitalks it works put your answer as a valid answer please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems all you need is to add a `<td>` to the row. You have :

```
<tr ng-if="device.expanded" ng-repeat-end="">
    <td colspan="6">gfhgfjhfjtjrtkjy</td>
</tr>
```

Change it to:

```
<tr ng-if="device.expanded" ng-repeat-end="">
    <td style="width: 30px;"></td>
    <td colspan="5">gfhgfjhfjtjrtkjy</td>
</tr>
```

This should add a `<td>` beneath the `plus/minus` icon. Additionally, you can style this `<td>` if you do not intent it to be appear as a column ( which I think is your intent).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry, I later realized this has already been suggested in the comment above by @Abhitalks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table width="100%">
  <thead style="background-color: lightgray;">
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 30px;"></td>
       <td><p>Name</p></td>
    <td><p>ID</p></td>
    <td><p>GPS date</p></td>
    <td><p>Adresse</p></td>
    <td><p>Company</p></td>
    </tr>  
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="device in MyDeviceObject">
      <td>
        <button ng-if="device.expanded" ng-click="device.expanded = false">-</button>
        <button ng-if="!device.expanded" ng-click="device.expanded = true">+</button>
      </td>
      <td><p>{{device.name}}</p></td>
      <td><p>{{device.uniqueid}}</p></td>
      <td><p>{{device.devicetime}}</p></td>
      <td><p>{{device.adress}}</p></td>
      <td><p>{{device.company}}</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr  ng-if="device.expanded" ng-repeat-end="">
      <td  colspan="6">gfhgfjhfjtjrtkjy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="device in MyDeviceObject">
      <td>
        <button ng-if="device.expanded" ng-click="device.expanded = false">-</button>
        <button ng-if="!device.expanded" ng-click="device.expanded = true">+</button>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2" align="center"><p>{{device.name}}</p></td>

      <td><p>{{device.devicetime}}</p></td>
      <td><p>{{device.adress}}</p></td>
      <td><p>{{device.company}}</p></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: I used colspan for 2 columns of "name" and "id" in last row.